# Simple example of Lambda Custom Resource in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am looking for the most simple example of having Lambda Custom Resource in Cloudformation.

Lets assume I have simple lambda:

```
def my_handler(event, context):
    message = 'Hello {} {}!'.format(event['first_name'], 
                                    event['last_name'])  
    return { 
        'message' : message
    }
```

I would like it to be called from Cloudformation template. Could you share the idea of doing this, please?

Comment: please follow this AWS sample Walkthrough
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html, please let me know if you have any doubt